# Force every method in a subclass to call a particular parent class method

Tags: c++, polymorphism, memoization

Let's say I have:

```
class Foo{
  void method();
}
```

And then I create:

```
class Bar : public Foo{

}
```

Where Bar has a lot of methods.  Is there any clever way I can force all methods defined in `Bar` to call `method()` from `Foo`?

The reason I wish to do this is for some clever memoization.  For certain function calls in `Bar` there can be some pre-processing to speed up future calls of that class by calling `method()`, thus I want to make a parent class `Foo` that invisibly handles the memoization, while the subclasses can happily and blindly focus purely on function definitions.

Comment: Invoking  `method` in the constructor is not possible? Solve the problem quite neatly.

Comment: I don't see how that solves things.  I want to call method as the first step of calling any method in Bar.  Maybe there's a clever way to use the constructor to set this up, though.

Comment: Need more information to give more details. Is the memoization done once, and then fixed?

Comment: The first time the method is called, a pre-processing procedure is called to speed up future evaluations.  On future evaluations, that information (which no longer changes) should be used somehow to speed up the evaluation of the method.

Comment: Then unless you have objects you ever use (and thus there is no point to computing the cached values) you might as well add the memoization to the `Foo` constructor. All of the work caching is done when you create the object and is all ready to use as soon as you call any of the methods.

Comment: The memoization needs to be done once per function, not once per object.

Comment: Ah. Recommend an edit to the question to make that clear. In that case, no. I don't have a good suggestion. The only things I can come up with are more difficult or confusing than calling the appropriate memoization method. Pity there is such thing as a per-object `static` local variable. That's exactly what you want.

Comment: Do all the methods of `Bar` have to call the same method of `Foo` ? If so, the [Excute-Around](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Execute-Around_Pointer) pattern might be interesting. See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42020373) for implementation suggestions.

Comment: Interesting - this sounds exactly what I'm looking for.  I'll look at this soon.  Thanks!