# How to intercept a method call?

Tags: c++, c++11

Please refer to this question first:

[How to ensure that every method of a class calls some other method first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019939/how-to-ensure-that-every-method-of-a-class-calls-some-other-method-first)

By overloading -> operator, we can call some function whenever -> is used. I was wondering if there is some way to figure out what function is being called as well?

Example:

```
struct foo{

void func1(){

}

void func2(){

}

}

struct Bar{

void someFunc(foo* f){
    f->func1();
}

}


struct Baz{

void someFunc(foo* f){
    f->func2();
}

}
```

In above example, Bar and Baz can call func1 and func2. One approach is that in every class we implement some code that calls a logging function informing it the method name being called.

The other approach is overloading the -> operator to call some log() function

```
struct LoggingFoo : private Foo {
    void log() const { }

    // Here comes the trick
    Foo const *operator -> () const { log(); return this; }
    Foo       *operator -> ()       { log(); return this; }
};
```

The only problem is how to pass some information to log(), so it knows what function is being called ?

EDIT:

Found this other approach:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34237/A-C-Style-of-Intercepting-Functions

Comment: This cannot be done, C++ simply doesn't work this way, on a fundamental level. Overloaded `operator->` gets called, before the target object's method, and the target object's method is not known to `operator->`, because that lies in distant future, and fundamental laws of physics are simply immutable. Furthermore, when the world is hammer everything else look like a nail. Every function in `Foo` can call this `log()`, as the first order of business. Problem solved.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - That is true, but then one needs to ensure that every function is updated to include the call to log() (which is what I mentioned as a possible approach in my question), but is more maintenance than some kind of hack like overloading -> . While what you're suggesting is a good way of doing things, I want to discover other ways of doing things which require less maintenance.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ is many things but "less maintenance" isn't one of them. Many have tried, none have found a magic button hiding somewhere in C++ itself, that makes it possible to automatically log class method invocations, with no work whatsoever.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you are right. was hoping for some way to generate code, or use a macro or some kind of hack to reduce the work...

Comment: I found this that seemed useful: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34237/A-C-Style-of-Intercepting-Functions Haven't fully understood this approach yet, but keeping it here since its useful.

Comment: Also note that in C++ you will often not even use pointers to access objects (to avoid unecessary new/delete calls). So if you follow C++ guidelines your intercept will not work anyway.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Pointers are not required here. Indeed, using pointers *breaks* this hacky way of intercepting method calls. The whole point is to use `->` on a **non-pointer** variable.

Comment: Anyway I have a core guideline for myself ; "Don't use tricks" they make code do surprising things that are not clear from the source code. When people see a `->` they should not expect these kind of (side) effects. Make a function that accepts a function then let that log and call the original function, it is much more explicit (and for implementation a template function might really help here).

Comment: Example of what I mean here : https://onlinegdb.com/ZPVgWlzng

Comment: This smells like a really bad design here. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, using this technique. At the point where `log()` is called, the method invocation hasn't happened yet, there is no contextual information about which method will be invoked.

What is happening here is, first the operator `->` is invoked, and then the `func2` invocation happens. It's no different than this:

```
void someFunc(foo* f){
  foo *f2 = f.operator->(); // log is called here
  f2->func2();              // method is invoked here
}
```

`log()` can't log something that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: You are correct. I can't accept the answer yet as 5 minutes have not passed yet so SO won't let me. Although I wish there was some way to intercept the method call.

Comment: @RahulIyer Code generation for a proxy class, or a preprocessor macro?

Comment: Great idea! Any idea how to do that ?